# The repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: linux-mint, pgadmin-4

Linux Mint 20.2

I want to install PgAdmin4.

Here OFFICIAL TUTORIAL

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Steps:
sudo curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3935  100  3935    0     0   4517      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4512

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

Result:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                      
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                               
Ign:11 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/uma pgadmin4 InRelease         
Ign:12 http://packages.linuxmint.com uma InRelease                  
Ign:13 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg InRelease
Err:14 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/uma pgadmin4 Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 443]
Err:15 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 443]
Hit:16 http://packages.linuxmint.com uma Release
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/uma pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Error:

E:  The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/uma pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: Duplicate of [E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808559/e-package-pgadmin4-has-no-installation-candidate)

Answer (score 6):

Please try to change /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list file lines to `deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 main`

Answer (score 4):

Change the url of the apt repository to apt-archive

As per the [Postgres instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ZN4OigxPJA236qlg%40msg.df7cb.de):

1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` (such as with `sudo nano`)
2. Replace the content with `https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg main`
3. Save and Exit (CTRL+X + Y + Enter if using nano).

Then run `sudo apt update` and proceed with the installation.

Comment: after pasting, control + X +++ ENTER

Answer (score 2):

**Bad tutorial boys**
Widuranga Dilruksha already solved op question. But i just want to expand it.
The following steps have to be performed on terminal

1. Execute: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list`
2. Delete everything you see there and paste the following text: `deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 main`
3. Save Changes by pressing `Ctrl` + `x` then `Y` and finally `enter`
4. Execute: `sudo apt install pgadmin4`

   Done. I Hope it clarifies the answer.

Comment: I get error: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT

Comment: That error comes from running pgAdmin 4. I'm still looking for a solution. I already post the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552921/the-pgadmin-4-server-could-not-be-contacted-in-linux-mint-20-2

Answer (score 1):

In my case the repo file was `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` (Elementary OS 6).

The other answers don't cover the case where, `sudo apt update` raises:

```
W: GPG error: https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8881B2A8210976F2
```

What solved this error was to get the PUBKEY `8881B2A8210976F2` and execute:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8881B2A8210976F2
```

Afterwards I was able to `sudo apt update` and then install postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Debian version is still LTS

PostgreSQL apt packages will be moved to apt-archive.postgresql.org once they have dropped the support for old Debian versions, that can be a reason why you are receiving this message

Today we have the following versions:

> - The next release of Debian is codenamed trixie — testing — no release date has been set
> - Debian 12 (bookworm) — current stable release
> - Debian 11 (bullseye) — current oldstable release
> - Debian 10 (buster) — current oldoldstable release, under LTS support
>
> https://www.debian.org/releases/ (Index of releases)

Postgresql has a wiki to keep this information

> Currently, we support
>
> - Debian buster (10), bullseye (11), bookworm (12), trixie (testing/13) and sid (unstable)
>   Ubuntu focal (20.04), jammy (22.04), lunar (23.04), mantic (23.10)
>
> https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt#PostgreSQL_packages_for_Debian_and_Ubuntu

They also update the News section telling us when those packages were moved to the archive url

> - 2023-11-05: Ubuntu bionic (18.04) and kinetic (22.10) removed from apt.postgresql.org.
> - 2023-08-17: Ubuntu bionic (18.04) moving to apt-archive.postgresql.org: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ZN4OigxPJA236qlg%40msg.df7cb.de
>
> https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt#News

So to solve the issue you can edit your url to target the subdomain `apt-archive` or update your Debian version

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with all other answers but before running

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

You have to update **apt** and this is made by
Executing the following command int terminal

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: It's not help. Same error

Comment: Well it didn't help me either but reinstalled ubuntu (from 21.0 to 20.04 LTS ) and faced the same problem again , But this time it worked with the commands from this site [link] https://www.tecmint.com/install-postgresql-and-pgadmin-in-ubuntu/

Comment: let me know what happened ) @a_subscriber

Comment: Not help. E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/uma pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 0):

anyone seeing this in 2023 or later, if it doesn't work by following the answers above, try replacing `bionic` with whatever is the codename of the ubuntu version your distro based itself of.

im running linux mint 21.2, apparently codenamed `vanessa`, based of ubuntu 22.04 `jammy`, after naming that it worked for me