# The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted in Linux Mint 20.2

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Folks i just installed pgAdmin 4 from [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/). But when i launch the application, it crashed, throwing me the following me error:
**The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:**

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/toastedguy2/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS: JS ERROR;JS LOG
  - LANGUAGE: en_US
  - USER: toastedguy2
  - XDG_SEAT: seat0
  - XDG_SESSION_TYPE: x11
  - SSH_AGENT_PID: 1388
  - SHLVL: 0
  - HOME: /home/toastedguy2
  - DESKTOP_SESSION: cinnamon
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop
  - GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
  - XDG_SEAT_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
  - LC_MONETARY: es_CR.UTF-8
  - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
  - CINNAMON_VERSION: 5.0.5
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 2430
  - MANDATORY_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path
  - QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME: qt5ct
  - LOGNAME: toastedguy2
  - XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
  - DEFAULTS_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.default.path
  - XDG_SESSION_ID: c2
  - GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING: 1
  - GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
  - PATH: /home/toastedguy2/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
  - GDM_LANG: en_US
  - GTK3_MODULES: xapp-gtk3-module
  - SESSION_MANAGER: local/toastedguy2-MS-7A39:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1316,unix/toastedguy2-MS-7A39:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1316
  - XDG_SESSION_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
  - LC_ADDRESS: es_CR.UTF-8
  - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
  - DISPLAY: :0
  - LANG: en_US.UTF-8
  - LC_TELEPHONE: es_CR.UTF-8
  - XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: X-Cinnamon
  - XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: cinnamon
  - XAUTHORITY: /home/toastedguy2/.Xauthority
  - XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/lightdm-data/toastedguy2
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
  - SHELL: /bin/bash
  - LC_NAME: es_CR.UTF-8
  - QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
  - GDMSESSION: cinnamon
  - LC_MEASUREMENT: es_CR.UTF-8
  - GPG_AGENT_INFO: /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
  - LC_IDENTIFICATION: es_CR.UTF-8
  - GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: stderr
  - XDG_VTNR: 7
  - PWD: /home/toastedguy2
  - XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg
  - XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/cinnamon:/usr/share/gnome:/home/toastedguy2/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
  - LC_NUMERIC: es_CR.UTF-8
  - LC_PAPER: es_CR.UTF-8
  - GDK_BACKEND: x11
  - NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 42741
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 06b1e235-ddd0-4070-9ac4-476a972202a2
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
--------------------------------------------------------

Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT
```

**How do i fixed it folks?**
Notes:
My OS is: Linux Mint 20.2 
PostgreSQL version: 12.8 (exact version by executing ***psql --version*** is: `psql (PostgreSQL) 12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`).
PostgreSQL service is **active**.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you find any solution? Thanks!

Comment: @user1185081 no, sorry. I'm using the command line interface.

Comment: I had the same issue. When I went into ```/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/``` I found that, for whatever reason, ```python3``` was linked to ```/usr/bin/python3.6```, however I have Python 3.8. The error went away when I removed and re-linked like ```sudo ln -s python3 /usr/bin/python3.8```. But, I then received an error about Flask not being installed which I could not resolve, despite Flask being on the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do was:

```
sudo apt remove pgadmin4-server
sudo apt install pgadmin4-server
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04 (and as a result upgrading Python 3.9 to 3.10), I had the same error. While at first it seemed the issue was that the python 3.9 symlinks inside `/usr/pgadmin4` were no longer linking to the correct place - but fixing those was not enough to solve the issue. It turned out that there were more dependencies to take care of.

The proper solution was that I needed to update the apt source URI link inside "Ubuntu Software & Updates" to point to the newer Ubuntu `jammy` apt URI:
from `https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/impish`
to `https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy`

[image]

As soon as I did that, and reinstalled pgadmin4-desktop and pgadmin4-server using `apt remove` and `apt install`, it had all the required dependencies and all worked.

Comment: Worked for me, also when upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS.
Also, probably `apt update` should be added before `apt install pgadmin4` to reload the changes of the source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is the solution that I got from the Internet,
installing python 3.8 will fix this problem

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.8
python3.8 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the ports running of your 'username' by:

> pkill '**username**' ex: pkill '**postgres**'

now use **pkill** to **safely** kill all the running process

> sudo pkill **postgres**

And at last, restart your postgres server.

> sudo service postgresql start